# Isolated Singular point at Infinity of tan z

Tags: complex-analysis

Out of curiosity, does tan z have an isolated singular point at infinity and why?

Thanks for any insight into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $\cos z=0$ at all odd multiples of $\pi/2$, and this set has $\infty$ as a limit point in the Riemann sphere.

Comment: Huh, that is pretty simple. Thanks.